# How to find total quantity for each part

Tags: mysql

```
    mysql> select * from Odetails;
+------+-------+------+
| ONO  | PNO   | QTY  |
+------+-------+------+
| 1020 | 10506 |    1 |
| 1020 | 10508 |    2 |
| 1020 | 10509 |    3 |
| 1020 | 10800 |    1 |
| 1021 | 10506 |    7 |
| 1021 | 10601 |    4 |
| 1022 | 10601 |    1 |
| 1022 | 10701 |    1 |
| 1023 | 10506 |    2 |
| 1023 | 10800 |    1 |
| 1023 | 10900 |    1 |
| 1024 | 10506 |   12 |
| 1025 | 10601 |    2 |
+------+-------+------+
13 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

> I need to count how much QTY there is for each part. There are repeats in parts. For instance, 10506 appears 4 times and has a QTY of 22. So in my table I would want it to appear like
>
> `10506       22`
>
> I can only get it to count the individual rows. I've looked up on how to get the quantity, not the rows but it does not seem to work. 
>   Here is what I have been trying:
>
> `select PNO, (count(QTY)*count(PNO)) as TOTAL from Odetails group by PNO;`
>
> `select PNO, count(*) as TOTAL from Odetails group by PNO;`
>
> This just gives me the number of times that the row has appeared
>   though.

Comment: `select count(PNO) ... group by PNO` always returns `1`; there is exactly one value of `PNO` in each group because this is how the groups are made: all the entries in a `group by PNO` have the same value for column `PNO`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple. Use `GROUP BY` and `SUM`

```
select pno, sum(qty) total
from Odetails
group by pno;
```